# C++ template type deduction from arguments of a function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-deduction, class-template

I have a template which looks something like this:

```
template< typename T, void (*f)( T& param )>
class SomeAction
{
...
};
```

`f` is used inside `SomeAction` (actually `f` is a class member, but I don't think it's matter).

Question is: can this be improved by removing 'typename T' from template parameters list and let compiler to deduce that type?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like that will be possible in C++17.

Comment: Template argument deduction only happens in template function calling in C++14. You have to specify template argument in template class instantiation even if it's non-type parameter

Comment: "*actually `f` is a class member*" As you've shown it, `f` is a template parameter – how can it also be a class member?

Comment: `f` is an identifier. How in the world can it also be a template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the C++17 feature you are looking for is [**Declaring non-type template parameters with auto**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html)

I can't test this yet because there is no compiler that support this feature yet, but presumably it would allow you to write a partial specialization of `SomeAction` that would deduce `T`

```
template<auto> class SomeAction;
template<void (*f)(auto&)> class SomeAction<f> {};

void foo(int&) { /* bla */ }

int main()
{
    // C++17 only, no compiler support yet
    SomeAction<f> s; // T deduced to be int
}
```

Comment: I think [template<auto>](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html) is more relevant.

Comment: @cpplearner: I fail to see how, since you can't just stick that in a type.

Comment: AFAIK In C++17 OP's code will be written as `template< auto > class SomeAction; template<typename T, void (*f)( T& param )> class SomeAction<f> { ... };`.

Comment: @cpplearner updated, still not 100% sure that this will be possible, no way to test it yet

Comment: I think this is invalid. The wording says that auto is valid as part of " and as a decl-specifier of the parameter-declaration's decl-specifier-seq in a template-parameter", it doesn't seem valid in the parameter type of the function (and unless they added the feature for c++17, `void (*f)(auto) = &foobar;` in local scope is just as invalid). It would seem to be valid if you said `auto (*f)()`, because there it's in the decl-specifier-seq of `f`.

Comment: However, it also says "When the value of the argument corresponding to a non-type template parameter P that is declared with a dependent type is deduced from an expression, the template parameters in the type of P are deduced from the type of the value.", so it I think that `template<typename T, void (*f)( T& param )>` should work, but not sure.